# Is it possible to link together multiple pieces to a variable (433,John,Smith)(236,Kevin,Smith)?

Tags: java, variables

I am thinking of a way to look up member ids in Java. But I first need to know if it is possible to store those ids in groups.

Problem is I want the member ID = FirstName, LastName;

How Do I store these together?

ID would be a integer but the names would be a string.

Like if look up  member id> 433 || I want to output > Smith, John

I also like to be able to search the name Smith and get > 433, Smith, John

How do I create a variable to store these so they are linked together like so?

I don't know what this is called or otherwise I would look it up myself. Anyone know where I can begin to research this?

Comment: I wanted to try to help, but I can't really understand your question, can you rephrase it please.

Comment: Agree with Marcelo that yours is a very confusing question. Consider editing it and re-phrasing it with the idea being that we can't read your mind.

Comment: After re-reading your question: some questions I have got: Have you already got something like a `Member` or `Person` class? Do you really want to look-up certain Members by one single property? I mean, if you happen to have a lot of members named "Smith", looking up "Smith" will yield more than one result. Are you actually looking for a Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group up your related values into a class such as:

```
public class Person {
    private final int id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(id) + ", " + firstName + ", " + lastName;
    }
}
```

And then, use a map to search up your values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Person> persons = new HashMap<Integer, Person>();
    persons.put(433, new Person(433, "John", "Smith");
    System.out.println(persons.get(433).toString());
    // The output for this is 433, John, Smith
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I *guess* you are looking for something like a [BiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).
It's basically a [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) which both maps `key` to `value` and `value` to `key`.
Here's an example with a standard map (which works only in one direction):

```
HashMap<Integer, String> yourMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>()
yourMap.put(433, "FirstName,LastName"); // associate key "433" with "FirstName,LastName"
System.out.println(yourMap.get(433)); // will print "FirstName,LastName"
```

Comment: And, `yourMap.inverse().get("FirstName,LastName");` would probably give him the answer to the other part of his problem. **Edit:** May be not. He needs to search for lastnames, so it won't be that easy.

Comment: Absolutely perfectly what I was looking for! Brilliant Tedil!

Comment: HashMap<Integer, String, String> yourMap = new HashMap<Integer, String, String>(); <<<<< Is that possible?

Comment: no, you would have to enclose your Strings in a class (such as Person, as propsed by Marcelo, or in a pre-defined class [such as mapentry, as proposed by PartlyCloudy])

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map` and take `Map.Entry<String,String>` as value.

```
Map<Integer,Map.Entry<String,String>> members = new HashMap<Integer,Map.Entry<String,String>>();

members.put(123, new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,String>("John", "Doe"));

members.get(123).getKey(); //returns John
members.get(123).getValue(); //returns Doe
```